# How do I set up oVirt Engine in Cockpit? I get an error with "deployment failed"

Tags: dns, virtual-machine, ovirt

I can't seem to set up an ovirt engine.

In my DNS (Pihole, so basically DNSMasq) I set local DNS record for the engine [192.168.0.235 -> ovirt-engine.MYDUMMY.DOMAIN], as well for the node [192.168.0.97 -> ovirt-1.MYDUMMY.DOMAIN; this is the IP I have set in router DHCP for the machine running oVirt].

During setup wizard in Cockpit, I set the DNS server to the local IP of my Pihole instance (192.168.0.66), and network to static (192.168.0.235). Under "Advanced", I also set the "HOST FQDN" to "ovirt-1.MYDUMMY.DOMAIN".

The FQDN validate, but if I click next, and try preparing VM, I get "Deployment failed". In the logs I get some permission errors:

```
cockpit-bridge
/var/lib/ovirt-hosted-engine-setup/cockpit/ansibleVarFilepQBj37.var.1: couldn't remove temp file: Permission denied
COCKPIT_DOMAIN  cockpit-bridge
PRIORITY    4
SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER   cockpit-bridge
_AUDIT_LOGINUID 1000
_AUDIT_SESSION  15
_BOOT_ID    7ff6008112ed4dec863cd7daa5c7a49d
_CAP_EFFECTIVE  0
_CMDLINE    cockpit-bridge
_COMM   cockpit-bridge
_EXE    /usr/bin/cockpit-bridge
_GID    1001
_HOSTNAME   ovirt-1.MYDUMMY.DOMAIN
_MACHINE_ID 5383b28b838b48bfb83e51082ce922be
_PID    72856
_SELINUX_CONTEXT    unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP  1604910992144612
_SYSTEMD_CGROUP /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-15.scope
_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID  6ab1b13e1e754c4385527d093d72880c
_SYSTEMD_OWNER_UID  1000
_SYSTEMD_SESSION    15
_SYSTEMD_SLICE  user-1000.slice
_SYSTEMD_UNIT   session-15.scope
_SYSTEMD_USER_SLICE -.slice
_TRANSPORT  journal
_UID    1000
__CURSOR    s=3f72f173a7184617893f8997f7e868c1;i=f2c;b=7ff6008112ed4dec863cd7daa5c7a49d;m=39c1504502;t=5b3a875953937;x=c0f9c1bd3c843a54
__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP   248056399106
__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP    1604910992144695
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? And how to fix it?

Comment: I never got this to work (this was using oVirt Node 4.4.2 and 4.4.3), but using [this guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-ovirt-on-centos/), I can set up the engine. So I'll manually install oVirt on centOS 8 instead of trying with the "all-in-one" image.

Comment: Did you ever get this working with manually installing oVirt in CentOS8 ?

Comment: @alexacallmebaka; I did, but abandoned it since the premature death of CentOS 8 was announced a few days after I got it working. I did, however, do a writeup you might be able to use as a [guide](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/installing-home-assistant-os-in-ovirt-on-centos/252709). I'll give it a go on Rocky Linux once I have some time on my hands.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing permissions for the directory `/var/lib/ovirt-hosted-engine-setup/cockpit/` worked for me!

Comment: How did you "fix" them? What are the proper permissions?